# apt-get install without debconf prompt

Tags: apt, debconf

I would like to install chef via apt non-interactively, but by default, apt installation brings up this prompt:

[image: apt install chef prompt]

Is there a way to skip this step during installation or pass a value to apt install? I'm only using chef-solo, so don't actually need the server component, so simply press return on this prompt.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can configure debconf into non-interactive prompt:

```
sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive aptitude install -y -q chef
```

If you find the complete key, you can also pre-configure the default value:

```
echo package package/key {boolean,string} {true, some string} | sudo debconf-set-selections
sudo apt-get install package
```

In this specific instance:

```
echo chef chef/chef_server_url string | sudo debconf-set-selections
```

To find the key, **after** installing the package you can look for it with `debconf-get-selections` (shipped in the `debconf-utils` package):

```
debconf-get-selections | grep chef
# URL of Chef Server (e.g., http://chef.example.com:4000):
chef    chef/chef_server_url    string
```

or with `debconf-show`:

```
debconf-show chef
```